# Refresh datatable on Ajax success

Tags: forms, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables and jquery dialog. Overall I have 3 forms and 3 datatables.
My script is working great but the thing I am struggling with is updating the correct datatable on success of ajax save (It doesn't even have to be the correct corresponding table, it could update all 3 tables on any of the 3 form saves.)

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Page with buttons for showing datatable/forms in dialog**

```
<div style="float:left;">
<button class="menubutton" id="view_academic">Academic</button>
<button class="menubutton" id="view_business">Business/Suppport</button>
<button class="menubutton" id="line_managers">Managers/Divisions</button>
<br/>
<br/>
</div>
<div style="float:right;">
<a href="line_managers_form.php" class="menubutton" id="add_line_managers">Add Managers/Divisions</a>
<a href="academic_form.php" class="menubutton" id="add_academic">Add Academic</a>
<a href="business_form.php" class="menubutton" id="add_business">Add Business/Suppport</a>
<br/>
<br/>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>


<div id="academic_list">
<h2>Academic Entitlements</h2>
<table class="dataTable" id="academic_table" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Year</th> 
<th>Employee</th>  
<th>Division</th>
<th>Contract</th>
<th>Entitlement</th>
<th>Line Manager</th>
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div id="business_list" class="the_options" style="display:none;">
<h2>Business & Manual Entitlements</h2>
<table class="dataTable" id="business_table" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Year</th> 
<th>Employee</th>  
<th>FT/PT</th>
<th>Weekly Hours</th>
<th>Division</th>
<th>Commencement</th>
<th>Entitlement</th>
<th>Line Manager</th>
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</div>

<div id="line_managers_list" class="the_options" style="display:none;">
<h2>Line Managers & Divisions</h2>
<table class="dataTable" id="line_managers_table" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Division</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Line Manager</th>
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**initialise Datatables**

```
$(function() {
    // Implements the dataTables plugin on the HTML table
    var $acTable= $("#academic_table").dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Filter:"
        },
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/academic_serverside.php",
        "iDisplayLength": 10,       
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "sPaginationType": "scrolling",
        "sDom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt>',
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true
        });     

});
$(function() {
    // Implements the dataTables plugin on the HTML table
    var $buTable= $("#business_table").dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Filter:"
        },
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/business_serverside.php",
        "iDisplayLength": 10,       
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "sPaginationType": "scrolling",
        "sDom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt>',
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true
        });     

});
$(function() {
    // Implements the dataTables plugin on the HTML table
    var $lmTable= $("#line_managers_table").dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Filter:"
        },
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/line_managers_serverside.php",
        "iDisplayLength": 10,       
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "sPaginationType": "scrolling",
        "sDom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt>'
        });     

});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".the_options").hide();
});
```

**Dialogs/datatables show/hide/open/close and AJAX save form:**

```
$(document).ready(dialogForms);
function dialogForms() {
  $('a.menubutton').click(function() {
    var a = $(this);
    $.get(a.attr('href'),function(resp){
      var dialog = $('<div>').attr('id','formDialog').html($(resp).find('form:first').parent('div').html());
      $('body').append(dialog);
      dialog.find(':submit').hide();
      dialog.dialog({
        title: a.attr('title') ? a.attr('title') : '',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          'Save': function() {
                submitFormWithAjax($(this).find('form'));
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $lmTable.fnDraw('');
                },
          'Cancel': function() {$(this).dialog('close');}
        },
        close: function() {$(this).remove();},
        width: 600,
        height: 500
      });
    }, 'html');
    return false;
  });
}

function submitFormWithAjax(form) {
  form = $(form);
  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    type: (form.attr('method')),
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function(data){
    $(this).dialog('close');
    $lmTable.fnDraw('');
   }
  });
  return false;
}

$(function() {

        $("#add_academic")
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $("#academic-form").dialog( "open" );
            });
        $("#add_line_managers")
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $("#line-managers-form").dialog( "open" );
            });
        $("#add_business")
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $("#business-form").dialog( "open" );
            });
        $("#view_academic")
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $('#academic_list').show();
                $('#business_list').hide();
                $('#line_managers_list').hide();
            });
        $("#view_business")
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $('#academic_list').hide();
                $('#business_list').show();
                $('#line_managers_list').hide();
            });
        $("#line_managers")
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $('#academic_list').hide();
                $('#business_list').hide();
                $('#line_managers_list').show();
            });

});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To update a table simply call `fnDraw()` on it. Since you are not using global variables, you must retrieve the table first

```
var $lmTable = $("#line_managers_table").dataTable( { bRetrieve : true } );
$lmTable.fnDraw();
```

EDIT - to show only the right table you could do something like:

```
function dialogForms() {
  $('a.menubutton').click(function() {
    var id = this.id;// Save the id of the clicked button
    var a = $(this);
    $.get(a.attr('href'),function(resp){
      var dialog = $('<div>').attr('id','formDialog').html($(resp).find('form:first').parent('div').html());
      $('body').append(dialog);
      dialog.find(':submit').hide();
      dialog.dialog({
        title: a.attr('title') ? a.attr('title') : '',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          'Save': function() {
                submitFormWithAjax($(this).find('form'), id);// Pass the id to the function 

function submitFormWithAjax(form, id) {
  form = $(form);
  var table_id;
  // Choose the table to display depending on the id, i made some guesses but adjust this
  switch(id){
    case 'view_academic': table_id = '#academic_table';
    break;
    case 'view_business': table_id = '#business_table';
    break;
    case 'line_managers': table_id = '#line_managers_list';
    break;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    type: (form.attr('method')),
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function(data){
        $(this).dialog('close');
        // Refresh table
        var oTableToUpdate =  $(table_id).dataTable( { bRetrieve : true } );
        $oTableToUpdate .fnDraw();
        // Hide all tables
        $('table').hide();
        // Show the refreshed
        $(table_id).show();

   }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, works great. Thank you! My buttons that show and hide the specific datatable, is there a way I can build that show/hide into the ajax success, ie show the correct table after saving one of the forms.

Comment: @Codded well that shouldn't be too difficult to implement, but i don't even see a form in your markup :) If you provide an example on jsfiddle i could help.read here on how to fake ajax call in jsfiddle  http://newcodeandroll.blogspot.it/2012/01/how-to-receive-response-from-ajax-calls.html

Comment: they are just simple POST forms initiated by the buttons in my question. they open up in dialog and are submitted to php script with mysql INSERT. submitFormWithAjax($(this).find('form'));

Comment: thanks for the solution, looks promising although it is not working as desired. It has stopped the table update working and is not showing the correct table. Any ideas?

Comment: @Codded maybe i did some stupid error, do you see anything in the console?Do you need to refresh a specific table on click or do you need to refresh always the same table?

Comment: all tables could be updated at the same time but I need to show the correct table from the correct form on save. does the CASE need to be the id of the button that shows the table? also on success dialog close ... this line $('table').hide(); is not hiding the tables so something is not working there

Comment: please see my buttons for showing tables and links for showing dialog.   $('a.menubutton').click(function() {
    var id = this.id;// Save the id of the clicked button
would get the id for the a that displays the form not the button that show/hides the table

Comment: @Codded maybe it's better if you open a new question and keep the working part :)

Comment: Could i private chat with you, i think i know what the issue may be but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Although the origional part of this answer is working, it does not always update on the first instance of save. Do you think it may be refreshing before saving? It does however work everythim after the first instance. Any Ideas?

Comment: @Codded that's strange. Have you checked with console.log or an alert that fnDraw() is really called?

Comment: seems ok in firefox. I tested earlier in opera.