# Datatable Export to Excel issues

Tags: jquery, datatables, export

I'm using jQuery DataTables plugin to construct tables and use the `sDom` option to have "Export to Excel" functionality with the .swf (`copy_csv_xls.swf`) file.

I build the table and this functionality works find without any issues. The issue comes when I use them in "tabs". I use Bootstrap vertical tabs and have a datatable in each tab. Whenever the tab is clicked, I had to reDraw the tables because of the alignment problem. I believe the "reDraw" is not creating issue. What happens is, when the data is populated in "Tab 1" with "Tab 1" being active, the "Export" works, but if the data is populated in "Tab 2", then the "Export" in Tab 2 doesn't work. The event itself is not firing.

Can anyone please tell me what would be the issue? Is there a solution or alternate option for this?

[image]

Comment: see this -> **http://iksela.tumblr.com/post/3445022287/using-jquery-ui-tabs-and-datatables-tabletools** and this -> **https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3783/issue-with-tabletools-2-0-on-hidden-tabs**

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad.. it worked fine after using the code given in the link you provided.

Comment: Can you please add solution suggested by @davidkonrad that worked for you as an answer so others could benefit from it?

Comment: From the link http://iksela.tumblr.com/post/3445022287/using-jquery-ui-tabs-and-datatables-tabletools, one of the post has the following code which I used in my application and it worked
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui){
            var ttInstances = TableTools.fnGetMasters();
            for (var i in ttInstances) {
                if (ttInstances[i].fnResizeRequired())
                    ttInstances[i].fnResizeButtons();
            }
        }
    });
}

Comment: Please add this solution as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, sounds like really good idea - after all it is the whole point with stackoverflow :)

Comment: @davidkonrad, if you can post that in answer, I can mark up as "answer"

Comment: Ésta puede una solución a tu problema.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848593/datatables-tabletools-multiple-tables-on-the-same-page